# How to initialize WPF Browser Application with Prism?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, mef

I'm starting to developp a WPF browser application using Prism framework with MEF, but my lack of experience with prism make it difficult to start.
All of the examples, tutorials or quickstarts that I've seen something like this :

```
Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
```

But this concerns only WPF window applications, right ? I mean, browser applications use Page and not Window. So i would like to know if it is possible to make a cast or to initialize my Shell by an other way.

Thanx in advance !

Comment: are you trying to google it...?

Comment: I did it, but surely very bad, didn't found what I was looking for..

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight shell is created in a similar manner:

Application.Current.RootVisual = (UIElement)this.Shell;

more information can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921096%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx

Comment: I know this, but the RootVisual property doesn't exists in WPF browser application